# Google tag manager get closest a text

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

i want use custom js variable to get card-title a shop-item-title-link's text for the event label = "product x".

1. Clicking the  click class fa-cart-plus to get the label product x;
2. Click the image to get the label product x

I've tried this js below, but it gets [object] [object] as the result.

```
function() {
  var el = {{Click Element}};
  return $(el).closest('card-title').text('a.shop-item-title-link');
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="card card-product">     
    <div class="card-image">
        <a href="#" title="product x">
            <img width="230" height="230" src="#" class="attachment-_thumbnail" alt="product x">    
        </a>
        <div class="ripple-container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h6 class="category"><a href="#">Items</a></h6>     
        <h4 class="card-title">
        <a class="shop-item-title-link" href="#" title="product x">product x</a>
        </h4>
        <div class="card-description">
            <p><span>product descirption</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="price">
                <h4><span class="Price"><span class="Price-currencySymbol">£</span>45.00</span></h4>
            </div>          
        <div class="stats">
            <a rel="nofollow" href="#" title="Add to cart">
                <i rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Add to cart" class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i>
            </a>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a very specific target, what you want to do is use `parent` and `sibling` together.

Try something like this:

```
return $(el).parents().siblings('.card-title').text();
```